# Online SharePoint Portal for testing purpose

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

Do we have any online site where we can create SharePoint Demo portal with master page and page layouts? I need to try a few things for a testing purpose.

Comment: When you have your test tenant, you can use https://lookbook.microsoft.com/ for inspiration as well as add the designs / layouts to your own tenant

Answer (score 1):

I have a test SharePoint site set up, you will be able to create this via https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program-get-started

You have a 12 month subscription with this program.

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Gavin

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a free developer SharePoint Online subscription for One Year, please visit here for register:

[Join the Office 365 developer program today!](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program)

I think this will meet your test purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe 30 days trail version of SharePoint online by using [This link](https://products.office.com/en-us/try)

Answer (score 0):

It depends ;-)

https://demos.microsoft.com/  is available for Partners and each MSDN subscription comes with a free tenant for dev and test

Answer (score 0):

For the - "Join the Office 365 developer program today!" option

You need a Visual Studio subscription to qualify for the instant sandbox.
"Any Visual Studio subscriber with a standard Professional or standard or monthly Enterprise subscription qualifies"